# What are the shortcuts for vert, edge and face selection in edit mode?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image: sho]

Can you help me? I dont know the shortcuts for these buttons.

Comment: Ctrl+1, Ctrl+2, Ctrl+3

Comment: 1, 2, 3 works also and you can cumulate modes with Shift+1, Shift+2, Shift+3

Comment: Thank you soo much :)